# why does redirect http://...local to https://...local/dashboard/ automaticly at firefox

Tags: laravel, xampp

i just have install new "laravel 6" project and i edit env file to

```
APP_URL=http://instegram.local
```

and host file to

```
127.0.0.1   instegram.local
```

and httpd-vhosts.conf in xampp to

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
SSLEngine off
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/instegram/public"
    ServerName instegram.local
</VirtualHost>
```

then i opened this on firefox

```
http://instegram.local
```

automatically it redirect me to

```
https://instegram.local/dashboard/
```

this problem on firefox only

*i restarted apache server

Comment: Could be some browser extension like HTTPS Everywhere. Try opening link in other browsers, if it's still redirecting then it can be project or server configuration.

Comment: it is work on chrome without problem.
the issue on firefox only.
HTTPS Everywhere installed in both.

Comment: after disable HTTPS Everywhere its work without redirect to https

Comment: Personally I haven't had such kind of problem with HTTP Everywhere in Chrome. I don't know about Firefox though. Look out for other extensions similar to it and try disabling them (including HTTPS Everywhere).

Comment: Great! I will add this as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**: First try opening project in other browser. If it still redirects then it's probably project or server configuration that causing the issue. If there are no redirects then move to next step.

**Step 2**: Try disabling extensions like [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) and such. These services redirects to HTTPS automatically for better security but that's not desired during development.